# Tidy evaluation: Adding an argument to a function that prevents gathering

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyeval

I am trying to build a function that gathers(pivot_longer) data.
In most cases, the function should gather all columns except one in the supplied data, but the user should be allowed to specify additional columns in the supplied data that shouldn't be gathered. This is something that the user will only rarely do, so the argument should default to no extra columns.

I think my function fails because it defaults to `NULL`.

Data:

```
library(tidyverse)
sample_data <- tibble(
  frame = rep(seq(1:20), 2),
  ID = rep(c(1,2), each = 20),
  a = rnorm(n = 40),
  b = rnorm(n = 40),
  c = rnorm(n = 40))
```

Function:

```
a_gather_function <- function(.data, also_dont_gather = NULL) {
  .data %>% 
  tidyr::gather(key, value, -frame, -{{also_dont_gather}})
}
```

The function works if I supply a column to the argument `also_dont_gather`

```
sample_data %>% 
  a_gather_function(also_dont_gather = ID) %>% 
  head(5)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  frame    ID key    value
  <int> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1     1 a     -0.626
2     2     1 a      0.184
3     3     1 a     -0.836
4     4     1 a      1.60 
5     5     1 a      0.330
```

But fails with default value `NULL`:

```
sample_data %>% 
  a_gather_function()

 Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator
```

I am quite sure the error comes from the function evaluating to `-NULL`, as the following code gives the same error:

```
sample_data %>% 
  tidyr::gather(key, value, -frame, -NULL)

Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Can you help me build a function that allows the user to specify additional columns that shouldn't be gathered but which defaults to no additional columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended solution (for this specific tidyselect case) is now to use `integer()` instead of `NULL` as default argument:

```
my_gather <- function(data, preserve = integer()) {
  tidyr::gather(data, "key", "value", -frame, - {{ preserve }})
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @Lionel. Does this mean that I, in general, should use integer() instead of NULL for default arguments, or is it only for this case?

Comment: Ah good point! I have edited the answer to make it clear it's only for this case.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**: This answer is outdated, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900856/1725177 for the recommended solution.

I have opened an issue in [tidyselect](https://github.com/r-lib/tidyselect/issues/110).

In the meantime you can use the quote-and-unquote pattern, and check whether you have captured the default `NULL` with `quo_is_null()`:

```
a_gather_function <- function(.data, also_dont_gather = NULL) {
  also_dont_gather <- enquo(also_dont_gather)

  if (rlang::quo_is_null(also_dont_gather)) {
    tidyr::gather(.data, key, value, -frame)
  } else {
    tidyr::gather(.data, key, value, -frame, -!!also_dont_gather)
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why this answer is supposed to be outdated. The integer solution did not seem to work for me, but this workaround with quo_is_null still works for me